# How to enable Flash in Firefox on Bodhi Linux?

Tags: firefox-extensions, linux-distributions

I've installed [Bodhi Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhi_Linux) 2.1.0 on an old Micron PC. Following the instructions, I've used the Midori browser to visit the [App Center](http://appcenter.bodhilinux.com/) to install both Firefox and the 32-bit Flash package. Unfortunately, Flash does not work in Firefox after this procedure (on my machine).

How to enable Flash in Firefox for Bodhi Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Instructions in [this thread](http://forums.bodhilinux.com/index.php?/topic/6436-flash-problem-with-browsers-firefox-midori/) worked for me.

To recap, download 32-bit deb package [from here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_import/maya/import/base/mint-flashplugin-11) to a temporary directory. Then execute in that directory:

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
sudo dpkg -i mint-flashplugin-11*.deb
```

Though perhaps not necessary, I rebooted the machine and it worked well.